# SQL Server 2000 scheduled Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Actually my job is take a backup data from a **mysql data table** to a **SQL Server table**.

So I created a DTS package in SQL Server 2000. When I manually run the the package, it runs  successfully without any errors, and the data got transfered from MySQL to SQL Server.

But when I run the package using schedule jobs I got below error

> DTSRun:  Loading...
>   DTSRun:  Executing...
>   DTSRun OnStart:
>   DTSStep_DTSDataPumpTask_1 DTSRun OnError:  DTSStep_DTSDataPumpTask_1,
>   Error = -2147467259 (80004005)    Error string:  [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified    Error source:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
>   Help file:      Help context:  0
>
> Error Detail Records:
>
> Error:  -2147467259 (80004005); Provider Error:  0 (0)
>   Error string:  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found
>   and no default driver specified
>   Error source:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
>   Help file:      Help context:  0
>
> DTSRun OnFinish:  DTSStep_DTSDataPumpTask_1 DTSRun:  Package execution
>   complete.

So please help me on this.....

Comment: To take a wild guess, the MySQL ODBC DSN is a user or file DSN but should be a system DSN. Jobs run as the SQL Agent account, not as you, so if something doesn't work when you run it as a scheduled job it's almost always either a) permissions or b) the user environment. And in this case "data source name not found" seems like a fairly clear error.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter mentioned, it could be a data source configuration problem - if you've set up your MySQL DSN as a user DSN rather than a system DSN, you'll need to change that. Open the ODBC configuration tool and go to the "System" table, rather than "User" (where it defaults) and create your data source there.

It could also be ax x64 problem - if the version of Windows you're using is x64, then the ODBC panel that opens by default shows x64 data sources. If you're using the x86 version of SQL Server (SQL 2000 has both), then you'll need to create the data source in the x86 ODBC administrator, which can be launched from:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Once they're launched, they look exactly the same, so it can be hard to tell which one you've got open. A general indicator is that x64 driver list is usually way shorter - on my machine, there are about 25 drivers in the x86 version and only 3 in the x64 version. Keep in mind that if you're using SQL 2000 x86, you'll also need to install the x86 version of the MySQL driver, even if your server is x64.